# Facebook Share not picking full url & meta name for custom url

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, coldfusion

I am trying to share a page of user on FB by giving the full url of that page. But it's not picking any title & other OG meta tags, which I have given on the page.

here is what I am using :-

```
<div class="img">
  <a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=https://pad.panda.org/content  /nav_content.cfm?uNC=86290929&uXNavID=123906' target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
                 '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
  <img src="images/facebook.jpg" alt="FaceBook" />
              </a>
```

Comment: There are spaces in the shared url: `https://pad.panda.org/content   /nav_content.cfm?uNC=86290929&uXNavID=123906`should be `https://pad.panda.org/content/nav_content.cfm?uNC=86290929&uXNavID=123906`

Comment: Beside Lego's comment, the URL needs a LogIn, so even IF there are all OG tags on the page you provided, Facebook won't be able to login into your site and retrieve the page details (since it can't look into the pages "protected" by the login)

Comment: You might want to generate the fb og tags dynamically with server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get rid of all warning in the [Facebook Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://pad.panda.org/content/nav_content.cfm?uNC=86290929&uXNavID=123906).

Comment: It's not only warnings, but also the fact the Facebook caches each URL once and the only way to make it re-cache the URL is 1. change the URL of the page (like by adding `?v=1` to the URL, but that will make you loose previous FB data on your URL, or 2. Use the Debug Tool to make Facebook go and re-read your page and cache it again. If you change any meta on the page in the future, just use the debug tool to make FB cache the changes.